# Get an iframe's current src

Tags: iframe, iframe-resizer

Is it possible to read the current src of the iframe ( cross domain ) through the resizedCallback?

I am trying to figure out a way to tell which page is loaded in the iframe and when a specific page is loaded trigger a refresh on the parent page.

I have no access to the iframe source.

Comment: Is this not possible?

Comment: That is not possible